# How to use the 'Plus' icon in w2ui

Tags: jquery, html, w2ui

I have added a custom button to a w2ui form but I would like it to be consistent with the other w2ui buttons. It has 'add' functionality so I would like to display the 'plus' icon similar to the one used in a w2ui toolbar. Can someone tell me the best way to achieve this?

My html is defined something like:

```
...
<div>
 ...
<button class="btn", name:="add">"Add"</button>
// How to give it the 'plus' icon?
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course realised just needed to use Firebug to get the style. So adding "w2ui-icon-plus" to your btn class does the trick